NextJs shared JWT between client and server
I have HTTP service in my NextJs application that manages the API calls to my external backend server acting like API endpoint (NodeJs app which has nothing in touch with NextJs)
The problem is:
I have to log in the user and get the JWT back.
I have to save the JWT somewhere so that my NextJs HTTP service injects the token into the headers before each request and it works from Client and Server side components, because now, sending from one of them it's undefined,  and I believe it's because it's saved in the cookies only for one instead of both
Here is my HTTP service:
       const headers: Record<string, string> = {
  language: "en",
  Accept: "application/json",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
};

type CustomRequestInit = RequestInit & {};

abstract class HttpFactory {
  abstract createHttp(url: string): Http;
}

abstract class Http {
  abstract builtUrl: string;

  abstract updateToken(_?: string): void;

  abstract get<T>(url: string, config?: CustomRequestInit): Promise<T>;
  abstract delete<T>(url: string, config?: CustomRequestInit): Promise<T>;
  abstract put<T>(
    url: string,
    data?: any,
    config?: CustomRequestInit,
  ): Promise<T>;
  abstract post<T>(
    url: string,
    data?: any,
    config?: CustomRequestInit,
  ): Promise<T>;
  abstract patch<T>(
    url: string,
    data?: any,
    config?: CustomRequestInit,
  ): Promise<T>;

  protected buildPath(path: string, trailingPath: string) {
    return `${path}${trailingPath}`;
  }
}

// FetchHttpFactory class implementing HttpFactory
class FetchHttpFactory extends HttpFactory {
  createHttp(url?: string): Http {
    return new FetchHttp(url);
  }
}

// FetchHttp class extending Http and implementing fetch methods
class FetchHttp extends Http {
  builtUrl: string;
  headers = headers || {};
  baseUrl = "http://localhost";
  token?: string = undefined;

  constructor(mainUrl?: string) {
    super();
    this.builtUrl = `${this.baseUrl}/api${mainUrl}`;
  }

  updateToken(token: string) {
    this.token = token;

    this.headers = {
      authorization: token,
    };
  }

  private async handleResponse<T>(response: Response): Promise<T> {
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  }

  async get<T>(url: string, config?: CustomRequestInit): Promise<T> {
    const { ...requestConfig } = config ?? ({} as CustomRequestInit);
    const response = await fetch(`${this.builtUrl}/${url}`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: { ...this.headers, ...(requestConfig.headers || {}) },
      ...requestConfig,
    });

    return this.handleResponse<T>(response);
  }

  async post<T>(
    url: string,
    data?: any,
    config?: CustomRequestInit,
  ): Promise<T> {
    const { ...requestConfig } = config ?? ({} as CustomRequestInit);
    const response = await fetch(`${this.builtUrl}${url}`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { ...this.headers, ...(requestConfig.headers || {}) },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      ...requestConfig,
    });

    return this.handleResponse<T>(response);
  }
}

export { HttpFactory, FetchHttpFactory };

And here is my SignIn page:
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { Button, Label, TextInput } from "flowbite-react";

import API from "@/api";
import { AuthActions } from "@/store/reducers/auth";
import { navPageWrapper } from "@/hoc/navPageWrapper";

const SignIn = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const form = new FormData(e.target);
    const email = form.get("email")?.toString();
    const password = form.get("password")?.toString();

    if (!email || !password) return;

    setIsLoading(true);

    try {
      const response = await API.DB.Auth.signIn({ email, password });

      if ("token" in response) {
        const token = response.token;

        // where to save the token so that I can retrieve it in the HTTP service

        dispatch(AuthActions.setToken(token));
        router.push("/home");
      }
    } catch (err: any) {
      console.error("SignIn error:", err.message);
    }

    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-1 items-center justify-center">
      <form
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        className="mx-2 w-11/12 rounded p-10 shadow-md sm:w-1/2 md:w-2/5 lg:w-3/12"
      >
        <div>
          <Label value="Email" />
          <TextInput
            value={"12asad@gmail.com"}
            name="email"
            placeholder="Email"
            type="text"
            required
          />
        </div>

        <div className="mt-4">
          <Label value="Password" />
          <TextInput
            value={"12345678@a"}
            name="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            required
          />
        </div>

        <div className="mt-4 flex flex-1 justify-end">
          <Button
            color="dark"
            type="submit"
            className="w-1/2 shadow"
            isProcessing={isLoading}
          >
            Submit!
          </Button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default navPageWrapper(SignIn);


I have similar application with separated backend and frontend. Consider to use Next-Auth for storing JWT tokens.

@Repkins could you please share some code? Actually all authorization is on backend side, all verification for each request are done there as well.

Following the comments I can show you my solution. (sorry for late answer)
You can use Next-Auth library which is good for OAuth2 or for JWT.
You need to create Credentials provider like this:
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
providers: [
    Credentials({
        name: 'Credentials',
        credentials: {
            username: { label: "Username", type: "text" },
            password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
        },
        async authorize(credentials) {
            const res = await fetch(<Backend authorization endpoint, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({ username: credentials?.username, password: credentials?.password }),
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
            })

            const user = await res.json()

            if (res.ok && user) {
                return user
            }

            return null
        }
    })
],

callbacks: {
    <callbacks>
},

session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
    maxAge: <session_valid_time>,
},

pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
    error: '/<some_err_page>'
}

}
In layout you need to wrap all {children} with import NextAuthSessionProvider from "./SessionProvider";
Then you can call this provider from login component like this:
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";
const result = await signIn("credentials", {
  username: <username value>,
  password: <password value>,
  redirect: <true or false for enabling redirecting after login>,
  callbackUrl: "<URL for callback>",
});

You can also specify Middleware.
Much more informations: https://next-auth.js.org/
Feel free to ask if something isn't clear.
